# Reading files using Windows API

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write a console program that reads characters from a file.
i want it to be able to read from a Unicode file as well as an ANSI one.

how should i address this issue? do i need to programatically distinguish the type of file and read acoordingly? or can i somehow use the windows API data types like TCHAR and stuff like that.

The only differnce between reading from the files is that in Unicode i have to read 2 bytes for a character and in ASNSI its 1 byte?

im a little lost with this windows API. 
would appretiate any help
thanks

Comment: ASCII = 1 byte per character. Unicode = 4 or a variable number of bytes per character, depending on the encoding, with possible endianness issues. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read the first chunk of the file in binary mode in a buffer (1 KB should be enough), and use the [`IsTextUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to determine if it's likely to be some variety of Unicode; notice that this function, unless it finds some "strong" proofs that it's Unicode text (e.g. a BOM) performs fundamentally a statistical analysis on the buffer to determine what "it looks like", so it can give wrong results; a case in which this function fails is the (in)famous "[Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)" bug.

Still, you can set how much guesswork is done using its flags.

Notice that, if your application does not really manipulate/display the text you may not even need to determine if it's ANSI or Unicode, and just let it be encoding agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Windows API has some utility methods for all kinds of text files.

In general, you need to read the BOM of the file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark), which will tell you which encoding of Unicode is actually used when you succeed in reading the character correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You read **bytes** from a file, and then parse these bytes as the expected format dictates.

Typically you check if a file contains UTF text by reading the initial [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and then proceed to read the remainder of the file bytes, parsing these the way you think they're encoded.

Unicode text is typically encoded as UTF-8 (1-4 bytes per character), UTF-16 (2 or 4 bytes per character), or UTF-16 (4 bytes per character)

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry, there is no difference between reading ANSI and UNICODE files. Difference has place only during processing